# save a txt document with php without html content

Tags: php, html

the file now is like this:

```
<p>User friendly buttons and IR Remote Control for easy control&nbsp;</p>
<p>Quality stereo headset enables user to enjoy hi-fi dynamic sound&nbsp;</p>
<p>Replaceable, rechargeable Li-polymer battery&nbsp;</p>
<p>Specs Video transmission frequency: 2414, 2432, 2450, 2468&nbsp;</p>
<p>Transmission distance: Approx 100m in open space&nbsp;</p>
<p>Bitmap Audio carrier wave: 6.0Mhz, 6.5mHz, + 50Khz&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>S/N Ratio: 50-70 db&nbsp;</p>
<p>Diplay: True Color Micro LCD&nbsp;</p>
<p>Resolution: Full color 922k pixels, 640*480&nbsp;</p>
<p>Viewing Angle: Diagonal 32 degree&nbsp;</p>
<p>Virtual Image Size: 80inches at 2M away&nbsp;</p>
<p>Contrast: 64:1, Color Depth: 24 bit &nbsp;</p>
```

I would like to get the same file but just the text (be carrefull there are things like &lt that i want them to be "<"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$html = '<p>Your &lt; html &gt;  &nbsp; here</p>';
$text = strip_tags($html);
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
echo $text;
```

Output: `Your < html >   here`

Strip tags doc: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Html Entity Decode doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$str = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($str));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will remove all the `<p>` for you and [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) will fix up your `&lt;` and co.